# Show node in view based on dropdown in seperated content type

Tags: views

I have two content types. One content type is 'sport' and a other content type is 'teacher'. I collected the content type 'teacher' with views and I display the fields in a block (this is important for my site set-up).

My content type 'sport' is seperated from the content type 'teacher' (this is also important for my site set-up). My content type ‘sport’ is the content type where my block ‘teacher’ is showing up.

My page is look like this:

[image]

If I create a new sport like basketball, the information of soccer changes into the information about basketball and the teacher should be Rob (choose from a dropdown when creating a page from content type 'sport').

Comment: Do you mean how to hide a block created from a specific content type when showing a node of a different content type?

Comment: Remember that a block has settings for where to put the block, and that is in the block settings, not the view settings. For example, for the _user login_ block, the settings are in admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure.

Comment: In particular, see this: http://d.pr/i/CVHv.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have two content types. 'Sport' and 'teacher' I want to be able to choose a teacher per sport (per node). As example: Soccer = teacher Peter, Basketball = teacher Jack. I created a block with views to show the teacher. When I choose nothing, the block is not showing up.

Comment: Please add that information in the question. I still don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to associate a _teacher_ node to every _sport_ node, you need one of the modules that add a reference field to a node. In that way, when creating a _sport_ node, you can select a _teacher_ node for that node.

Comment: You really need to edit you question. In the comment you talk of content types (_teacher_ and _sport_) your question doesn't talk of, which talks of _block_ and _page_ content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I followed the following steps:

- I have created an entity reference (in the content type sport)
- I have created a view with relationship to the entity reference
- I have created a contextual filter, content Nid with the relationship I created before to the entity reference field.

Everything works now!